# importing audio file onto python-3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am getting this error when I try to import audio file, how do i import this audio file?:

---

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ce3f03976f66> in <module>()
----> 1 Fs, oooh = wavfile.read('oooh.wav') #my vowel sound
      2 Audio(oooh, rate=Fs)

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py in read(filename, mmap)
    231         mmap = False
    232     else:
--> 233         fid = open(filename, 'rb')
    234 
    235     try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'oooh.wav'
```

and this is the code I have written thus far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.io import wavfile
import scipy.signal as sig
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
from IPython.display import Audio
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

Fs, oooh = wavfile.read('oooh.wav') #my vowel sound
Audio(oooh, rate=Fs)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. If you have a Python question, always tag it with the generic [python] tag, and if appropriate, you may add a more specific tag.

Comment: Now, your error message seems to be pretty straightforward - the file isn't being found at that path. Are you sure you are in the right working directory? In a jupyter notebook, you should be able to use `pwd` and `ls` shell commands to check...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing audio track (wav or aiff) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489927/importing-audio-track-wav-or-aiff-in-python)